# How to avoid incorrect reusing of custom cells on MvxGridView?

Tags: android, xamarin, binding, mvvmcross, android-custom-view

1. I have the Android app page (on fragment) with MvxGridView with such layout:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <MvxGridView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@color/white"
       android:numColumns="1"
       android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
       android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
       local:MvxBind="ItemsSource DayGraphsItems"
       local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/day_graph_item" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. I have a custom view for drawing graph:

   ```
   public class GraphView : View
   {
       Paint mPaint;
       Bitmap mBitmap;
       Canvas mCanvas;
       Path mPath;
       Paint mBitmapPaint;

       public List<string> Data { get; set; }

       public GraphView(Context context, Android.Util.IAttributeSet attributeSet) : base(context)
       {
           mPaint = new Paint();
           mPaint.AntiAlias = true;
           mPaint.Dither = true;
           mPaint.SetARGB(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
           mPaint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.FillAndStroke);
           mPaint.StrokeJoin = Paint.Join.Round;
           mPaint.StrokeCap = Paint.Cap.Round;
           mPaint.StrokeWidth = 1;
           mPaint.TextSize = 24;

           mPath = new Path();
           mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
          mBitmapPaint.SetARGB(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xff, 0xff);
      }

      protected override void OnSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
      {
           if (w > 0 && h > 0)
           {
               mBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
               mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

               _canvasHeight = h;
               _canvasWidth = w;

               DrawTheGraph(Data);
           }
       }

       public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
       {
           canvas.DrawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
           canvas.DrawPath(mPath, mPaint);
           canvas.Restore();
       }

       private void DrawTheGraph(List<string> data)
       {
          // here is drawing of the graph which works well
       }
   }
   ```
3. I have the custom binding

   ```
   public class GraphCustomBinding : MvxConvertingTargetBinding
   {

       public static string Name = "GraphCustom";

       public GraphCustomBinding(GraphView target) : base(target)
       {
       }

       protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
       {
           var data = new List<string>();
           data = (List<string>)value;

           var targetGraphView = (GraphView)target;
           targetGraphView.Data = data;
       }

       public override Type TargetType
       {
            get { return typeof(GraphView); }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Binding is correctly registered in setup.
5. I have item's layout for the elements of DayGraphsItems list

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:paddingLeft="15dp"
       android:paddingRight="15dp"
       android:paddingTop="15dp"
       android:paddingBottom="15dp">
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
       style="@style/TextViewCurrentConditionsHeader"
       local:MvxBind="Text Title" />
   <Pogoda.Droid.GraphView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="300dp"
       android:padding="5dp"
       local:MvxBind="GraphCustom Data, Mode=TwoWay" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

**EDIT:**

6. DayGraphsItems is a list of DayGraphItem which is given as follows:

   ```
   public class DayGraphItem
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }

       public string Title { get; set; }

       public List<string> Data { get; set; }
   }
   ```
7. View is on fragment:

   ```
   [Register("pogoda.droid.DayGraphsFragment")]
   public class DayGraphsFragment : BaseFragment<DayGraphsViewModel>
   {
       public const string TAG = "DayGraphsFragmentTag";

       public override string UniqueImmutableCacheTag
       {
           get
           {
               return TAG;
           }
       }

       public override Android.Views.View OnCreateView(Android.Views.LayoutInflater inflater, Android.Views.ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
           return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.day_graphs_layout, null);
       }
   }
   ```

**Problem:** The graphs are drawn correctly, but in the case when there are more cells than could be displayed at once on the screen, after I scroll down I see the cells which was drawn before instead of new ones (seem to be reused).

**QUESTION: How to avoid this and display fresh graphs instead of these "scrolled out from the top"?**

Comment: what type is `DayGraphsItems` in your ViewModel? BTW your `GraphCustom` should be `Mode=OneWay` because that implementation of custom binding that does not fire changes from the view to the viewmodel

Comment: You are right - it should be `Mode=OneWay`, though it is not the reason of problems. I've completed question on your request adding point 6 - there is definition of item list.

Comment: In order to see if it is a problem of the control or the viewmodel or inbetween I'd replace your `MvxGridView` with an `MvxRecyclerView`  to see if the behaviour keeps going on

Comment: added also point 7 with fragment. thanks for your answers. will check with `MvxRecyclerView`. will inform you :)

Comment: I think that some adater should be involved, but have no idea how to implement it in my case

Comment: you can use the `MvxRecyclerView` directly without specifying an adapter; it's just to test if the behaviour is the same

Comment: Yes, there is the same problem when using `MvxRecyclerView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution which works for me is

Create `EnhancedMvxListView` and replace `MvxGridView` using it in point 1.

```
    public class EnhancedMvxListView : MvxListView
    {
        public EnhancedMvxListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs, new EnhancedMvxAdapter(context))
        { 
        }

        public EnhancedMvxListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, IMvxAdapter adapter) : base(context, attrs, new EnhancedMvxAdapter(context))
        { 
        }
    }
```

where `EnhancedMvxAdapter` is the following

```
public class EnhancedMvxAdapter : MvxAdapterWithChangedEvent
{
    public EnhancedMvxAdapter(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override View GetBindableView(View convertView, object dataContext, ViewGroup parent, int templateId)
    {
        templateId = GetTemplateId(dataContext);

        var view = base.GetBindableView(convertView, dataContext, parent, templateId);

        var context = dataContext as DayGraphItem;

        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.graphTitle).Text = context.Title;
        view.FindViewById<GraphView>(Resource.Id.graphDrawing).Data = context.Data;

        return view;
    }

    private int GetTemplateId(object data)
    {
        return Resource.Layout.day_graph_item;
    }
}
```

And finally in file in point 2. I've replaced

```
    public List<string> Data { get; set; }
```

with

```
    List<string> _data;
    public List<string> Data
    {
        get
        {
            return _data;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && value != _data)
            {
                _data = value;

                if ((int)_canvasWidth == 0 || (int)_canvasHeight == 0)
                    return;

                mBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap((int)_canvasWidth, (int)_canvasHeight, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
                mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

                DrawTheGraph(Data);
            }
        }
    }
```